# Putting condition inside or outside method

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have to choose between two designs which do exactly the same thing.
Which one would be better from maintenance effort perspective ? SRP violation ?

**Design #1**

```
if(ConditionVerified())
{
    Process();
}

public void Process()
{     
    // Do a lot of work ...
}
```

**Design #2**

```
Process();

public void Process()
{
   if(ConditionVerified())
   {
        DoProcess();
   }    

}

public void DoProcess()
{
    //Do a lot of work ...
}
```

Comment: I say save space, chars and key strokes, go with #1.

Comment: In design #2, Process() violate SRP we agree ?

Comment: @Tim : I have to stop the process if the condition is false.

Comment: Regarding `#2`, IMO it would be better to `//Do a lot of work` in `Process` rather than having a separate `DoProcess` method (and if you don't always want to check the condition, I'd rather go with a boolean parameter to indicate whether we should check the condition than separating it into multiple methods).

Comment: Option3: `public void Process(bool forceProcess)
    {     
        if(forceProcess || ConditionVerified())
        {
            // Do a lot of work ...
        }
    }` It depends on if the verification is related to the process and it's unlikely that it will ever change. If the verification is not part of or related to the process it doesn't belong into the method.

Answer (score 1):

If `process` can be started from multiple places in your code, and `condition` always follows the same requirements, then option #2 might be a viable design. In all other cases, the extra hop is un-useful and I would stick with #1.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method has no return type for an error / success condition, I would recommend you use Design #1. 
However if you are doing a lot of work you should consider how a failure or a pre-execution condition may affect the operation. In which case you should go with Design #2.

Personally I default to #2 because I like to keep all pertinent logic contained, however there are good reasons NOT to go with #2:

- You don't need the variables for anything other than performing the validation
- You use the method somewhere else and the conditional logic is not required